# Unable to export data from ArcGIS 3D Analayst interpolate line button & create profile graph

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, 3d-analyst

I have lost the facility to export data to Excel from the profile graph facility in the ArcMap 3D toolset. The interpolate line function works and I get the profile graph when selected and I get the dropdown menu when I click properties but the system does not respond when I select some of the options on this sub-menu including the path to data export. I have repaired ArcGIS; no difference. I have a MacPro + external display and it is possible that the functions selected that are not displayed are mapped "off screen".

If so, how would you force a reset on the menu locations to their defaults?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to reset the application user profile to bring back the defaults in the application:

[How To: Perform a soft ArcGIS Desktop reset](https://support.esri.com/en/Technical-Article/000014992)

Comment: Hi Yogesh, thanks for your reply I have tried this unfortuantely  it does not work . My config is Macbook pro + extra display/bootcamp/arcgis 10.7